# Updating a column with concatenated value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, sql-update

I have an id field (`int` type) and `varchar` field.

I have to concatenate both columns and store the result to another column with data type `nvarchar`;

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, of course:

```
UPDATE dbo.YourTable
SET NVarcharField = CAST(id AS NVARCHAR(10)) + CAST(VarCharField AS NVARCHAR(50))
WHERE (some condition)
```

Comment: Is there ever any need in explicit cast/conversion betweeen NVarChar and VarChar type values and when, I wonder?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your new NVARCHAR column as computed one.

```
CREATE TABLE TestInsertComputedColumn  
( 
    ID int, 
    Name VARCHAR(50) 
);   

insert into TestInsertComputedColumn(ID,Name) 
     select 8, 'vgv'; 
select * from TestInsertComputedColumn; 

ALTER TABLE TestInsertComputedColumn  
      ADD FullName As Name + cast(id as nvarchar); 

select * from TestInsertComputedColumn; 
--drop TABLE TestInsertComputedColumn;
```